# Matlab "Out of Memory" Solutions?

Tags: matlab, memory

```
fname = dir('*sir');
[tmp, head] = loadsir(fname(1).name);
dayH = zeros(length(fname),size(tmp,1),size(tmp,2));

% use temporary array to simplify 3d array creation
for i=1:1
  tmp = loadsir(fname(i).name);
  dayH(i,:,:) = tmp;
end
```

I have this code above but all I get is:

```
Error using zeros
Out of memory
Error in dataAnalysis (line 4)
dayH = zeros(length(fname),size(tmp,1),size(tmp,2));
```

Comment: what are the values of `length(fname), size(tmp,1) and size(tmp,2)`

Comment: FYI, a nice feature of functions like `zeros` in matlab is that you can pass in an array as the argument, so you can simplify your call to `zeros([length(fname) size(tmp)])`. Of course that won't help your out-of-memory error!

Comment: Do this calculation: `length(fname)*size(tmp,1)*size(tmp,2)*8/1e6`. This will give you the number of MB of RAM you need to store this temporary array. If that is larger than a few hundred, you might want to try a different approach.

Comment: If you really need a big matrix, but with only a few values: look into sparse matrices.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays in Matlab are stored in consecutive chunks of memory. You are probably running out of memory because your computer doesn't have a continuous block of memory large enough to store the entire matrix.

You need to:

1. reduce the size of the matrix, or
2. Use a variable type that allows memory to be saved in discontinuous chunks.

If you don't plan on populating the entire matrix then try reducing its size using a `sparse matrix` as suggested by @Dennis Jaheruddin

If you plan on filling the matrix then consider splitting it into cells.

```
zeroMat = zeros( size(tmp,1), size(tmp,2) );
daysH = repmat( {zeroMat}, [length(fname), 1] );
```

Each individual cell will still require enough memory for a matrix of size `size(tmp,1) x size(tmp2)`. Unless these numbers are huge you should probably be fine.